# change height of google plus 1 button

Tags: google-plus-one

i would like to know how to change the css of the google +1 button size tall (the button with the bubble counter on it).

default is 60 pixel but i need 70 pixel

let me know please

thanks

```
 <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the image can't be done other than what they've allowed for on the page to customize.

But you can add 10px of padding to the top or bottom of your div (or 5px top 5px bottom) that surrounds the `<g:plusone`. This way it will fit nicer in your 70px high content area, and you can top justify, bottom justify or center it vertically.  My example centers is vertically.

```
<div style="padding:5px 0;">
  <g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however, I was able to get around this issue in most modern browsers, by using a transform on the iFrame's parent div. Obviously, you would need to transform it uniformly, to prevent the G+ from becoming deformed, so the data-width may need to be reduced if the element becomes too wide.

Since most of the time the div will be displayed inline-block, setting the transform origin to somewhere along the bottom will prevent most alignment issues.

Then all you need to do is add some extra margin to the opposite side to offset its new large size, prevent it from overlapping other items, and ensure it's aligned vertically with other elements on the page.

```
/* ID provided by Google in my example matches this format */
div[id^="___plusone_"] {
    /* Cross browser support for transform */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);

    /* Cross browser support for transform origin */
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom left;

    /* Margin right is used here since origin is set to bottom left */
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```